# Validate 3-field unique combination

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have Product table with `size` ,`pos`, `color` and `order_id(FK to Order table)` fields.

I want to validate unique combination of those field not per table but
per `order_id`.

My rules for `unique` in product table looks like this.

```
 [['size', 'pos', 'color'], 'unique',
 'targetAttribute' => ['size', 'pos', 'color']];
```

It does validate but compare combinations in all records of a table.

How can I achieve it to validate with also given order_id?

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want to "validate unique combination of those field" and then you add completely different fields in `targetAttribute`. Based on the first part of your question only I would say this is enough: `[['size', 'pos', 'color'], 'unique',
 'targetAttribute' => ['size', 'pos', 'color', 'order_id']]`

Comment: @Bizley, sorry typo , but If  I set only those properties, it checks the uniqueness with all the records in the table

Comment: I don't understand your request. My comment's code does that - every time you validate `size` or `pos` or `color` it checks if combination of `size-pos-color-order_id` is unique in Product table.